# Función Lambda no funciona en un tk.Button

Tags: python, tkinter

Este es un ejemplo simplificado de un problema que tengo en otro código. Cuando llamo a la función `lambda` del botón este no cambia el texto de la `label` y no sé por qué. Agradecería que alguien me explicara.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text_var = tk.StringVar()
text_var.set("Hello")

l1 = tk.Label(root, text=text_var.get())
l1.pack()

tk.Button(root, command=lambda: text_var.set("Good Bye"), text="Change").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en la línea:

```
l1 = tk.Label(root, text=text_var.get())
```

El argumento `text` permite asignar un determinado texto (`str`) al `Label` en el momento que es instanciado, posteriormente podríamos cambiarlo mediante `l1.config(text="nuevo texto")`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

l1 = tk.Label(root, text="Hola")
l1.pack()

tk.Button(root, command=lambda: l1.config(text="Good Bye"), text="Change").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

En tu caso le asignas al `Label` **el texto** contenido en la variable **en ese instante**, pero no asocias la variable al widget, no difiere realmente de lo que se hace arriba. Por lo tanto, cuando se pulsa el botón el contenido de la variable cambia, pero no se refleja en el `Label`.

Para asociar una variable al `Label` y que cualquier modificación de ésta se refleje de forma automática e inmediata en el widget asociado, debes usar el argumento `textvariable` y pasarle una referencia a la `StringVar`, no su contenido:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text_var = tk.StringVar(root)
text_var.set("Hello")

l1 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=text_var)
l1.pack()

tk.Button(root, command=lambda: text_var.set("Good Bye"), text="Change").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme otra vez jajaja. Una pregunta. ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar ```text``` y ```textvariable```?

Comment: He editado la respuesta, básicamente text permite indicar una cadena a mostrar en el label, mientras que textvariable asocia una variable cuyo contenido se mostrará en el label, actualizándose cuando esta se actualice de forma automática.

Comment: Okey supuse que era eso. Thanks man.